# Java Set Implementation with more than max int elements

Tags: java, set, max

does there exist an Implementation of a Java Set that can handle more than MAX_INT elements. I know that a Set can store more than MAX_INT, but for example the size() method of a HashSet returns only an int. So i am looking for a ready to use implementation of a Set that can actually handle more than MAX_INT elements.

Alternatively i have to implement such a set by myself, but maybe there are already existing implementations?

Best regards,
Benjamin

Comment: How much RAM do you have?

Comment: 8 GB; the Set should only store references to the objects, not the objects itself. Its a cartesian product problem. I hope that than 8 GB are enough.

Comment: A reference needs 4 bytes. Integer.MAX_VALUE is 2^31 - 1. So, to store 2^31 references (and only that), you already need 2^31 * 4 bytes which equal to 8 GB of RAM. So if you add the memory needed for the set itself and for all the objects referenced you need way more RAM than what you have. So what's the point in having such a huge set? You probably need a database.

Comment: A database would slow down the iterations. In general you are right, but i use the Google Guava Sets.cartesianProduct() method to create the cartesian product. In the java source they describe that:

"Performance notes: while the cartesian product of sets of size m, n, p is a set of size m x n x p, its actual memory consumption is much smaller. When the cartesian set is constructed, the input sets are merely copied. Only as the resulting set is iterated are the individual lists created, and these are not retained after iteration."

So the memory is not a problem. So i just want a bigger Set.

Comment: If you're ready not to have a standard Set anyway, and all you want is to iterate through the cartesian product, then why don't you implement the iteration by yourself?

Comment: I'm sorry, but i think i don't get the question. Actually the Google Guava Sets.cartesianProduct implementation uses for example the .size() function of a set, which returns a int. My idea was to use the Sets.cartesianProduct implementation, but extend it to be able to create/store more than MAX_INT combinations, therefore the own implementation of the set. Afterwards the result of the cartesian product will already be iterated by myself... Ah, or do you mean i should implement the creation of the cartesian product by myself?

Comment: That's what I mean. Just create a class that holds your N sets, returns the cartesian product size as a long rather than an int, and allows iterating through all the combinations.